# Manually disabling job in PLSQL

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql, jobs

I have a Plsql job that is executed for each 10 min. This job calls a procedure. The procedure takes some files from the log pool and process these files (process here means separating good and bad records).
Sometimes the files in the log pool are very large(4GB), so it takes some time to process these files, probably more than 10 min.

So my question is: while the procedure is still processing these files, the job which is executed after every 10 min will interrupt the procedure from executing the previous file ?

Answer (score 0):

For jobs (dba_jobs) the NEXT_DATE is calculated after the job finish.